# URLSession 'Network connection is getting lost' in background state

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am using URLSession to fetch the live preview of the image from the server. But whenever I am keeping app into the background state for just second and coming back to foreground state I am getting following error message.

**load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 
"The network connection was lost."**

Please let me know if you guys come across such problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code, but you probably need to call `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask` when your application enters the background with an active network task.

Comment: @Paulw11 I will update question with code

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger How did u make this working